# Change default variable name in trigger PowerDesigner

Tags: sql, triggers, naming-conventions, sybase, powerdesigner

....Hi all!....

I wonder if it's possible and how to change default variable name in triggers template of PowerDesigner 16.5.

e.g. in template:

```
create trigger % TRIGGER % after insert order % ORDER % on[ % TABLQUALIFIER % ] % TABLE %
    referencing new as new_ins
for each row
begin
```

I want to change **new_ins** to **new_val** because I use another naming convention.

Could anyone give me a tip where in PowerDesigner options I can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the template trigger text in the `Trigger Templates` tab of the `DBMS` definition, that you can access through `Database>Edit Current DBMS...` in your model, or `Tools>Resources>DBMS...`.

Yours is the `AfterInsertTrigger` in this list.